# A proof of $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(Axx^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

In [this post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753129/how-can-i-show-that-xtax-mathrmtraxxt) my answer was downvoted. Unfortunately, I cannot find the mistake and the downvoter did not comment. The question was to prove that $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(Axx^T)$.

The argument I gave was to note that trace is linear hence if trace agrees with $x^TAx$ on the basis vectors then the two must be equal (linear transforms are uniquely determined by what they map the basis vectors to). But it's clear that for the standard basis the equality $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(Axx^T)$ holds (I mean, really clear, in the sense that the necessary computation is simple enough so you can do it in your head).

Apparently this is incorrect and I would like to know why. Thank you in advance.

A thought: Of course the maps involved are really *bi* linear (not just linear) but I believe the argument stays the same.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that linearity is moot because $x^TAx$  isn't a linear expression in $x$ (_or_ its coefficients); $(x+y)^TA(x+y)\neq x^TAx+y^TAy$...

Comment: The maps aren't bilinear either; that requires them to take two arguments, but they only take one. The maps $(x,y)\mapsto x^TAx$ and $(x,y)\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(Ayx^T)$ are bilinear though, so you could apply your argument to those, and then specialise to $x=y$.

Comment: @MattPressland That doesn't work; bilinearity isn't preserved under substitution.  In fact, that's the crux of the matter.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Maybe I'm just having a brain-freeze; surely if you check the two maps I wrote above (correcting the typo in the first one) agree on a basis, then they are equal by bilinearity, and in particular they are equal when the two inputs are the same. I can't see what I'm missing... The difference between this and what the OP said is that you have to check all $n^2$ pairs of basis vectors, not just the $n$ pairs consisting of the same basis vector twice (which I agree is not enough). This is the (longer) argument in Martin's answer.

Comment: @MattPressland Ahhh, no; I just misunderstood your argument - I thought you were specializing _before_ using the bilinearity, but what you say makes perfect sense.  Mea culpa.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki No problem, it happens to us all...hence me finding it very easy to believe I had got it wrong!

Comment: @MattPressland Is the typo in the first one that it should be $(x,y) \mapsto x^T A y$? I see you edited the comment and it's not clear to me if you had already corrected the typo you are referring to.

Comment: @user89987 Yes, that is correct - unfortunately I only noticed after the time limit for editing comments had elapsed.

Answer (score 4):

The key flaw in your argument is that (bi)linearity isn't preserved under duplication of arguments; if $f(x,y)$ is a bilinear function of $x$ and $y$ then that doesn't imply that $g(x)=f(x,x)$ is a linear function of $x$.  The easiest way to see this is to specialize to the one-dimensional case and look at $f(x,y)=xy$; this is obviously bilinear in $x$ and $y$, but $g(x)=f(x,x)=x^2$ certainly isn't a linear function of $x$.

Comment: Great, especially your first comment to the question. $x^TAx$ is obviously not linear. And adding Matt's comment it's obviously not bilinear either. And putting it together: even if it was bilinear, duplicating the argument of a bilinear map does not result in a linear map.

Answer (score 3):

$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ satisfies $x^T A x = 0$ for the standard basis vectors, but not in general.

As for the identity $x^TAx = \text{tr}(Axx^T)$, it's linear in $A$.  Is it true for a matrix with one nonzero entry?

Answer (score 3):

Both expressions are quadratic on $x$, not linear. So if $x=\sum x_je_j$ where $e_j$ are the canonical basis vectors, you have
$$
x^TAx=\sum_j\sum_kx_jx_k\,e_j^TAe_k.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\text{Tr}(Axx^T)=\sum_j\sum_kx_jx_k\,\text{Tr}(Ae_ke_j^T).
$$
Now you could verify that $e_j^TAe_k=\text{Tr}(Ae_ke_j^T)$ to finish the proof. This is certainly easy, but I wouldn't say it deserves to be claimed as true without justification.

Now the main point is that the original proof can be achieved with way less effort. If you think of $x$ as the first element in an orthonormal basis (as both expressions are quadratic on $x$ we can assume that $x^Tx=1$), then $x^TAx$ is $A_{11}$ when $A$ is represented in such a basis. And using that $xx^T$ is the rank-one projection onto the span of $x$, $\text{Tr}(Axx^T)=\text{Tr}(xx^TAxx^T)$, which is again the $1,1$ entry of $A$ in an orthonormal basis whose first element is $x$.

Comment: Sorry why does the last equality $\mathrm{Tr}(Axx^T) = \mathrm{Tr}(xx^T A xx^T)$ hold?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathrm{Tr}(Axx^T) = \mathrm{Tr}(x^Tx A xx^T)$?

Comment: No, $x^Tx=1$ in my answer, so the equality you wrote holds but gives you nothing. The equality $\mathrm{Tr}(Axx^T) = \mathrm{Tr}(xx^T A xx^T)$ holds trivially because $(xx^T)(xx^T)=xx^T$, and you can cycle products inside the trace.

Comment: Then I am sorry but I don't get it. Why does $(xx^T)(xx^T) = xx^T$ imply the equality and what does cycle products mean?

Comment: $$\text{Tr}(Axx^T)=\text{Tr}(Axx^Txx^T)=\text{Tr}(xx^TAxx^T).$$ The trace has the property that $\text{Tr}(ST)=\text{Tr}(TS)$ for all $T,S$.